# Symbols for Outer Joins

Tags: symbols, database

I'm looking for a way to typeset the symbols for [outer joins](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_%28relational_algebra%29#Outer_joins), that is ⟕ [U+27D5](http://www.charbase.com/27d5) onward.

There seems to be nothing in symbols-a4. Note that I'm not looking for ⋊ [U+22C9](http://www.charbase.com/22C9) as this represents a semijoin.

[This post](http://theno23.livejournal.com/17363.html) presents a custom eps (for only one of the three symbols) and a anonymous comment suggests using an `ifsym` timing diagram (I'm awed by the lateral thinking but the result looks ugly).

Answer (score 37, accepted):

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\def\ojoin{\setbox0=\hbox{$\bowtie$}%
  \rule[-.02ex]{.25em}{.4pt}\llap{\rule[\ht0]{.25em}{.4pt}}}
\def\leftouterjoin{\mathbin{\ojoin\mkern-5.8mu\bowtie}}
\def\rightouterjoin{\mathbin{\bowtie\mkern-5.8mu\ojoin}}
\def\fullouterjoin{\mathbin{\ojoin\mkern-5.8mu\bowtie\mkern-5.8mu\ojoin}}

\begin{document}
\[A\leftouterjoin B\]
\[A\rightouterjoin B\]
\[A\fullouterjoin B\]
\end{document}
```

[image: example]

Answer (score 41):

With [`unicode-math`](http://ctan.org/pkg/unicode-math) and XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX, you can use these symbols directly:

```
% compile with xelatex or lualatex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmathfont{XITS Math}

\begin{document}
$A ⟖ B$
\end{document}
```

[image: example]

They also have aliases: `\leftouterjoin`, `\rightouterjoin`, `\fullouterjoin`

Comment: Wow! This is as it should be. One more reason to switch away from pdfTeX.

Answer (score 1):

Another solution is the one presented in [this](http://dbai.tuwien.ac.at/education/dm/resources/symbols.html) web page.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} 
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{ifsym}


\begin{document}
$A {\tiny \textifsym{d|><|d}} B$
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

egreg's answer modified to use `\Join` instead of `\bowtie`. Had to modify values in a code I don't quite understand so correct me if I made a mistake. It looks good on my machine though.

```
\def\ojoin{\setbox0=\hbox{$\Join$}%
  \rule[-.02ex]{.25em}{.4pt}\llap{\rule[1.10ex]{.25em}{.4pt}}}
\def\leftouterjoin{\mathbin{\ojoin\mkern-8.5mu\Join}}
\def\rightouterjoin{\mathbin{\Join\mkern-8.5mu\ojoin}}
\def\fullouterjoin{\mathbin{\ojoin\mkern-8.5mu\Join\mkern-8.5mu\ojoin}}
```

Answer (score 0):

Better version, which uses `\Join` symbol which looks like real DB join symbol than `\bowtie`!

```
\def\ojoin{\setbox0=\hbox{$\Join$}%
\rule[0.1ex]{.27em}{.4pt}\llap{\rule[1.3ex]{.27em}{.4pt}}}
\def\leftouterjoin{\mathbin{\ojoin\mkern-5.8mu\Join}}
\def\rightouterjoin{\mathbin{\Join\mkern-5.8mu\ojoin}}
\def\fullouterjoin{\mathbin{\ojoin\mkern-5.8mu\Join\mkern-5.8mu\ojoin}}
```

Comment: The horizontal lines and the `\Join` symbol aren't properly attached if I compile your code. Could you turn your snippet into a full minimal document and include a screenshot of the output (like egreg and Caramdir did)?

Comment: I think it depends on individual LaTeX compiler and language/font packages installed. Because for me iKs's code did not work, and so I just tweaked `\rule[0.1ex]` and `\rule[1.3ex]` until it showed correctly in my compiled output.
So you may want to try that at your end.

Comment: iKs' and egreg's solution both work fine using `pdflatex` without any special font packages, so it seems like you're doing something non-standard that breaks iKs' code on your setup. Would you mind posting a complete minimal example document?

Comment: Ummm. I will see if I can, but yes, I surely am using a special stylefile required for my document, and I am unsure if that stylefile has some special commands or TeX `\def`s which might be interfering. (And right now I don't have a lot of bandwidth to dig deeper into that, I just needed this to be working)!!
Oh, and I am using `pdflatex` too!