# Left outer join symbol (⟕)

Tags: symbols, unicode

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Symbols for Outer Joins](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/20740/symbols-for-outer-joins)

I want to insert the Unicode symbol ⟕ (&#10197; LEFT OUTER JOIN). Who can give me an minimal LaTeX example containing the character?

Comment: You're looking for the "left outer join" symbol "⟕". The question has already been asked before: [Symbols for Outer Joins](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/20740/symbols-for-outer-joins)

Answer (score 4):

To use unicode characters in LaTeX, you can load `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}` in your preamble. Then you can either just type the symbol if it's on your keyboard, or you can hold <kbd>Alt</kbd> and enter the unicode number on your number pad if you use Windows, or press <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>u</kbd> and then enter the unicode number if you're using Ubuntu.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\begin{document}
©
\end{document}
```

This will only work if the font you're using supports the character, which most likely isn't the case for Unicode 10197 (my system can't display it, and compilation with this character fails for me).

You might be looking for a different symbol: Using [Detexify](http://detexify.kirelabs.org/) to look up your symbol yields `$\forall$`, which looks like this

[image]

which is similar, but not identical, to Unicode 10197, which, according to [fileformat.info](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/10197/index.htm) looks like this:

[image]

Comment: But... The character I want to input is &#10197; I found here.http://coolshell.cn/wp-content/uploads/2009/08/Unicode-table.htm             Is your character in hex?

Comment: @Times: Sorry, yeah, I assumed the symbol to be in hex. The problem with the character missing from the font is the same with this symbol, though. Maybe you should post a new question, "How can I insert a Left Outer Join Symbol in LaTeX".

Comment: Is there a tool like Detexify that recognizes unicode?