# Symbols for outer joins not displaying

Tags: xetex, symbols, unicode-math, database, join

As suggested in an answer to [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/20740/symbols-for-outer-joins), I'm using `unicode-math` and `XeLaTeX` to typeset symbols for different kinds of joins in relational algebra. However, when I commands `\leftouterjoin`, `\rightouterjoin` and `\fullouterjoin` as in the answer, nothing is being displayed.

Here's the MWE:

```
\documentclass{book}[serbian]
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{ifsym}
\usepackage{unicode-math}


\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\setmainlanguage[Script=Latin]{serbian}
\setmainfont{Times New Roman}

\newfontfamily\cyrillicfont{Times New Roman}
\let\cyrillicfonttt\ttfamily

\begin{document}
    \chapter{Spajanje}
    \[R \leftouterjoin S\]
    \[R \rightouterjoin S\]
    \[R \fullouterjoin S\]
\end{document}
```

Here's the output:

[image]

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 3):

You get

```
Missing character: There is no ⟕ in font [latinmodern-math.otf]/OT:script=math;language=DFLT;!
Missing character: There is no ⟖ in font [latinmodern-math.otf]/OT:script=math;language=DFLT;!
Missing character: There is no ⟗ in font [latinmodern-math.otf]/OT:script=math;language=DFLT;!
```

in the log file, which means that the default Unicode math font doesn't have the symbols. Since you're using Times as text font, you also need a compatible math font, which Latin Modern isn't anyway.

Adding `\setmathfont{STIX2Math.otf}` will choose STIX Two, which has a much fuller symbol coverage and is Times compatible.

Answer (score 1):

It worked after I included the line:

```
\setmathfont{xits-math.otf}
```