# Non-standard Outerjoin Symbol

Tags: symbols, database

I was looking at the notation from the textbook I'm using to learn relational algebra and other DBMS related information, and I noticed that I don't know how to typeset the symbol shown below.

[image: Image from textbook]

I know [there is a command in the amssymb package](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/20740/symbols-for-outer-joins) and related packages to produce the standard unicode symbols for outerjoins. Is there a package somewhere using this symbol?

Comment: Welcome to tex.sx.  You can add `\circ` above the join symbol using `\stackrel` (in `amsmath`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might use `\overset{\circ}{\bowtie}` to get

[image]

However, this doesn't really resemble the symbol you show. You can try

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\circleouterjoin}{\mathrel{\mathpalette\circleouterjoin@\relax}}
\newcommand{\circleouterjoin@}[2]{%
  \ooalign{%
    \hidewidth\raisebox{1.1\height}{\scalebox{0.9}{$\m@th#1\circ$}}\hidewidth\cr
    $\m@th#1\bowtie$\cr
  }%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

The \emph{outerjoin} $R\circleouterjoin S$

In subscripts $X_{R\circleouterjoin S}$

\end{document}
```

[image]

You may play with `0.9` (scaling factor) and `1.1` (raising factor) until you're fully satisfied.

You might not be happy with `\bowtie` that has “interlacing”.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\outerjoin}{%
  \mathrel\triangleright
  \mathrel{\mkern-2mu}%
  \mathrel\triangleleft
}
\newcommand{\circleouterjoin}{\mathrel{\mathpalette\circleouterjoin@\relax}}
\newcommand{\circleouterjoin@}[2]{%
  \ooalign{%
    \hidewidth\raisebox{1.1\height}{\scalebox{0.9}{$\m@th#1\circ$}}\hidewidth\cr
    $\m@th#1\outerjoin$\cr
  }%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

The \emph{outerjoin} $R\circleouterjoin S$

In subscripts $X_{R\circleouterjoin S}$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Explanation: in `\bowtie` the backing up is 3mu.

Answer (score 1):

With :

```latex
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\newcommand{\outerjoin}{\overset{\circ}{\bowtie}}
\begin{document}
The \emph{outerjoin} $R \outerjoin S$.
\end{document}
```

you obtain:

[image]